# Shell script for .bat to quit telnet window upon logging off app

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an app' which is started from within `run.bat`; this connects through a telnet server.

Upon logging off the app' the end user is returned to the `telnet` service which we don't want, *as workers would have access to it*.

So I'm looking for a way to close the window but keep the telnet server active at the same time.

This is the `telnet` `alluser.bat` which will lead into our app' `run.bat`:

**ALLUSER.BAT:**

```
echo  ================================================================
echo   .\scripts\allusers.bat
echo   this script is executed for all users
echo   delete/rename it if you dont need it
echo  ================================================================
chcp 437
cd %USERPROFILE%
start "" "C:\davinci\dvrfapp\run.bat"
```

**RUN.BAT:**

```
start C:\davinci\dvrfapp\dvrfapp.exe c:\davinci\dvrfapp\config.json
exit
```

The `exit` part on the `run bat` is to close the previous window left open for the **ALLUSER.BAT**.

Comment: Why using `start "" "C:\davinci\dvrfapp\run.bat"`, why not `call "C:\davinci\dvrfapp\run.bat"`?

Comment: Cool. Thank you for that. Now I can remove the "exit" from the run.bat.

Comment: I figured it out. Putty has to be set to "close window on exit: only on clean exit" and I had to add "exit" at the end of the run.bat. Thanks.